# C++ Template Function to Iterate Over any Collection Member Field

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am attempting to write a template function that iterates over a user-specified field within some collection of structs.  For example, I want to write the following C++:

```
struct Example {
    int a;
    bool b;
};

template<std::function<Field& (Class)> GetField, typename Field, typename Class>
void myFunc(std::iterator<Class> begin, size_t const length) {
    cout << length << endl;
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < length; ++begin, ++i) {
        Field const &field{ GetField(*begin) };
        // Forward field to some other template function
        anotherTemplateFunction<Field>(field);
    }
}

void main() {
    Example exArray[]{ {5, true}, {8, false} };
    std::list<Example> exList{ exArray, exArray + _countof(exArray) }

    // Examples of how I would like to call myFunc...
    myFunc<Example::a>(exArray, _countof(exArray));
    myFunc<Example::b>(exList.begin(), exList.size());
}
```

The above doesn't work, but hopefully the intent is clear.  How can I write the myFunc template method to accomplish generic iteration over some field of each iterated item?  Alternatively, if there is some way (in Boost or the Standard Library) to directly create an iterator over `exArray[i].a`, that would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple if you know the pointer to member syntax and the likes. Unfortunately is so rarely used, is kind of an esoteric feature of the language:

```
template <class T> void foo(T);

template <auto Field, class It>
auto myFunc(It begin, It end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        foo((*begin).*Field);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Example> v{{5, true}, {8, false}};

    myFunc<&Example::a>(v.begin(), v.end()); // will call foo<int>(5) , foo<int>(8)
    myFunc<&Example::b>(v.begin(), v.end()); // will call foo<bool>(true) , foo<bool>(false)
}
```

For the `template <auto Field` you need C++17.

For C++11 the syntax is more verbose:

```
template <class T, class F, F T::* Field, class It>
void myFunc(It begin, It end)
{ /* same */ }

int main()
{
    std::vector<Example> v{{5, true}, {8, false}};

    myFunc<Example, int, &Example::a>(v.begin(), v.end()); // will call foo<int>(5) , foo<int>(8)
    myFunc<Example, bool, &Example::b>(v.begin(), v.end()); // will call foo<bool>(true) , foo<bool>(false)
}
```

---

A little bit OT to your question, but I don't understand why you complicate yourself with that initialization of `std::list`. In C++ your first container of choice should be `std::vector`.

Also there is no `std::iterator`

Comment: I actually am using `std::vector` currently.  The reason I didn't put that in the question is because I'm guessing if I did, the first answer I got back would have assumed the first argument to `myFunc` could always be `Class*`.  I wanted higher quality answers, so I chose a type that requires `myFunc` to accept both pointers and iterators.

Comment: Yes, but an iterator isn't a pointer.  I didn't want answers that *only* worked for pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck on VS2017u2, which doesn't have auto template parameter support.  However, I was able to use the declaration `template<typename I, typename T, typename F> void myFunc(I begin, size_t length, F T::*field);`.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually use is something like:

```
void main() {
  std::array<Example, 2> exArray{ {5, true}, {8, false} };
  std::list<Example> exList{ exArray.begin(), exArray.end() };

  auto access_a = [](Example& e)->int&{ return e.a;};
  auto access_b = [](Example& e)->bool&{ return e.b;};
  myFunc(exArray.begin(), exArray.end(), access_a);
  myFunc(exList.begin(), exList.end(), access_b);
}

template<class ForwardIt, class Accessor>
void myFunc(ForwardIt begin,ForwardIt end, Accessor accessor) {
    cout << end - begin << endl;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++) {
      // Forward field to some other template function
      anotherTemplateFunction(accessor(*it));
    }
}
```

Please notice how I used `std::array` instead of a raw c style array.
If you have access to a c++11 compiler, `std::array` (or `std::vector`) should always be preferred over raw c arrays. [ES.27](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-bad-82)

In order to need less boilerplate code, consider using some serialization libraries which solve this "iterating over class fields" problem, for example [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Comment: This answer along with pointer to member parameters has it.  You don't need lambda functions, and can simply pass &Example::a directly as the second parameter.